# StackPanel.ActualHeight is always zero

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I create a `StackPanel` in run-time and I want to measure the `Height` of the `StackPanel` like this:

```
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
panel.Children.Add(new Button() { Width = 75, Height = 25 });
Title = panel.ActualHeight.ToString();
```

but `ActualHeight` is alwasy zero. How can I measure the `Height` Of the `StackPanel`?

Comment: `ActualHeight` will be 25 anyhow on render because StackPanel grows indefinitely to accommodate its children. What you want to achieve here?

Comment: as I said,I want to create a StackPanel and some controls on it and then print it by PrintDialog.

Comment: I have posted an answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: is the panel being renderized in the screen? Can you see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to measure size without loading content on UI, you have to **call `Measure` and `Arrange` on containing panel** to replicate GUI scenario.

Be notified that how's WPF layout system works, panel first calls `Measure()` where panel tells its children how much space is available, and each child tells its parent how much space it wants. and then `Arrange()` is called where each control arranges its content or children based on the available space.

I would suggest to read more about it here - [WPF Layout System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745058%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

That being said this is how you do it manually:

```
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
panel.Children.Add(new Button() { Width = 75, Height = 25 });
panel.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
panel.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, panel.DesiredSize.Width, panel.DesiredSize.Height));
Title = panel.ActualHeight.ToString();
```

Comment: Dang! I tried this very thing with `double.NaN` instead of `double.PositiveInfinity` and got an exception. Never considered trying w/ `PositiveInfinity`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but this code works:

```
this.SetBinding(Window.TitleProperty, 
                new Binding()
                     {
                         Source = panel,
                         Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight")
                     });
```

In general, you won't be able to access the size of a stackpanel until it is laid out and rendered. This happens prior to the panel's `Loaded` event, so you could handle that event and deal with it then.

Comment: I want to create a StackPanel and some controls on it and then print it by PrintDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try get the `ActualHeight` in `Loaded` event:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var panel = new StackPanel();
    var button = new Button();

    button.Width = 75;
    button.Height = 25;

    panel.Children.Add(button);
    panel.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(panel_Loaded);

    MainGrid.Children.Add(panel);
}

private void panel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel = sender as Panel;
    Title = panel.ActualHeight.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to raising loaded event without adding it to a grid?

Comment: You can use [FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.loadcontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to force elements in a template to load to a temporary visual tree, but that isn't always useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
panel.UpdateLayout(); //this line may not be necessary.
Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(panel);
var panelHeight = bounds.Height;
```

Comment: No, the answer is -Infinity

Comment: try calling the UpdateLayout like I edited the question (first line).

Comment: you can also try to wrap the StackPanel inside a Grid, because StackPanel has some problems with calculating size really.